# Loading images dynamically slow, jquery, php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I am developing a website that has some photos to display, divided in albums.
Each photo's path is stored in a database.

I want to display the photos using a jquery gallery plugin. The problem is that the photos are taking forever to load, which sometimes causes the browser to crash.

I have tried lazy loading with galleria, lazyload and jpreloader, but so far the problem remains.

For the development of the site i use CodeIgniter. So far i have tried two methods for loading the photos.
1) By passing them from the controller to the view.
2) By using jquery and ajax.

Which method is better from a performance perspective?

The number of the photos isn't really big, just 17 with total size about 5mb.

If anyone could help me, i would be extremely gratefull.

Comment: How much does it normally take for your server to respond to a request? Because 17 photos are 17 request. Usually shouldn't be a problem, but if your server is not configured properly, or overloaded...

Comment: What I would do is store the path of the images in a javascript variable at page load, then write the HTML `<img src="...` when the user wants to view the section of the photo gallery. If you are displaying all 17 images at once, then that might just be your problem.

Comment: Also, if you must display all 17 images on one page at once, then [lazyload](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) should work if you're implementing it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to compress/resize your images on the server side, preferably one thumb at size of your gallery & one between 720 & 960 for the full size,

thumbs will be really lightweight, full size maybe 850kb for the 17

i give you an  easy to use php  class dealing with all image format :

```
<?php
  class scratch_utils_imgresize 
      {

    static function resize($file_path
                          ,$new_file_path
                          ,$img_width
                          ,$img_height
                          ,$scale) {
       $new_width = $img_width * $scale;
       $new_height = $img_height * $scale;
       $new_img = @imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
       switch (strtolower(substr(strrchr($file_path, '.'), 1))) {
        case 'jpg':
        case 'jpeg':
            $src_img = @imagecreatefromjpeg($file_path);
            $write_image = 'imagejpeg';
            $image_quality = isset($options['jpeg_quality']) ?
                $options['jpeg_quality'] : 75;
            break;
        case 'gif':
            @imagecolortransparent($new_img, @imagecolorallocate($new_img, 0, 0, 0));
            $src_img = @imagecreatefromgif($file_path);
            $write_image = 'imagegif';
            $image_quality = null;
            break;
        case 'png':
            @imagecolortransparent($new_img, @imagecolorallocate($new_img, 0, 0, 0));
            @imagealphablending($new_img, false);
            @imagesavealpha($new_img, true);
            $src_img = @imagecreatefrompng($file_path);
            $write_image = 'imagepng';
            $image_quality = isset($options['png_quality']) ?
                $options['png_quality'] : 9;
            break;
        default:
            $src_img = null;
    }

    $success = $src_img && @imagecopyresampled(
        $new_img,
        $src_img,
        0, 0, 0, 0,
        $new_width,
        $new_height,
        $img_width,
        $img_height
       ) && $write_image($new_img, $new_file_path, $image_quality);
       // Free up memory (imagedestroy does not delete files):
       @imagedestroy($src_img);
       @imagedestroy($new_img);
       return $success;

   }
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Finally i used the Galleria plugin with the lazy option. I created seperate thumbnails using the code you gave me, and now they load just fine.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to define your performance bottleneck.

- Is it your database query response?
- Is it your PHP script?
- Is it your javascript?
- Is it your browser?
- Is it your image server's upload speed?

If you know it's the server's upload speed, which is usually the case, then you should not output into HTML all of the images at once. This can be solved in many ways, of which I'll only cover 2...

1. The "long page" format
2. The "paginated/tabbed" format

**1)** Use the jQuery plugin [LazyLoad](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) properly like so:

```
// include jQuery and lazyload plugin
<script>
// Make sure $ is still short for jQuery (no conflict exists with other libraries)
$(function() {
  $("img.lazy").lazyload();
});
</script>
<body>
<img class="lazy" data-original="img/example.jpg">
```

**2)** [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) tabbed method (documentation [here](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/))...

```
<?php
// json_encode the albums you get from your db
$jsonEncoded = json_encode($returned_array_from_db_of_albums);
?>
<!-- include jQuery and jQuery UI -->
<script>
$(function() {
  var albums = <?php echo $jsonEncoded; ?>;
  // iterate through albums to find the album names and build our tab menu (expressed in HTML already below) and the associated <div>s where the images will ultimately go
  // e.g. $('#album-names').html(album_names_html);
  // then $('#albums').append(album_names_divs_html);

  function displayAlbum (id) {
    // id parameter will be the id of the <a> tag you clicked below
    // fetch the images from the albums array you defined above associated with the album id
    // build the <img> tags and set the associated $('div#'+id).html() to your output
  }

  $('#albums').tabs();
  displayAlbum('first-album'); // first-album should be the id of the first album in your albums array
  $('#albums ul li a').click(function() {
    displayAlbum($(this).attr('id'));
  });
});
</script>
<body>
<div id="albums">
  <ul id="album-names">
    <!-- following 2 <li>s should be generated by your javascript as explained above -->
    <li><a href="#album-1">Album 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#album-2">Album 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <!-- like my comment above, so should these -->
  <div id="album-1"></div>
  <div id="album-2"></div>
</div>
```

Also make sure your images are as compressed as possible as one of the other answers suggested. However, I don't recommend compressing the images every time someone hits the page, like in a PHP script. Be sure to compress the images beforehand.

Comment: Your comments put me into thinking, found the Galleria lazy option and got it to work. lazyload works fine indeed.